# Access Denied for Akamaighost Server When Doing a Request

Tags: c#, akamai

Can anyone help me why I'm getting this in C#? but in python/curl/postman I'm not getting any error.Is there any option to HttpClient that causing this error?

> 403 - Forbidden
>
> Access Denied
>
> ## Access
> Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access
> "http://www.asd.com/api/1.0/geoip"
> on this
> server.
>
> Reference #18.4eab3417.1650796514.11071801

```
async Task Main()
{
    string url = "https://www.asd.com/api/1.0/geoip";

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = null,
        UseProxy = false,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
    };
    using (var client  = new HttpClient(handler)){
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36");
        var res = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var final = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}\n", (int)res.StatusCode, res.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(final);
        
    }
}
```

SOLVED ALREADY by adding the X509Certificates